# Iphone uitextfield auto format like contacts app tag issue

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uitextfield

I have a form screen on my iphone and I am trying to replicate the Iphone Contacts app where it will auto complete the following format for the phone number:
(233)323-2323.

I am very close I am able to see the format update in the textfield but the 4 other text fields are not working now.  I am unable to edit them.  I narrowed it down to the shouldchangecharactersinrange function.

Please see code below.

Thanks.

```
    quick look at the method:
            - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
    if(([textField tag] == 2)){
    int length = [self getLength:textField.text];
    //NSLog(@"Length  =  %d ",length);

    if(length == 10)
    {
    if(range.length == 0)
    return NO;
    }

    if(length == 3)
    {
    NSString *num = [self formatNumber:textField.text];
    textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@) ",num];
    if(range.length > 0)
    textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[num substringToIndex:3]];
    }
    else if(length == 6)
    {
    NSString *num = [self formatNumber:textField.text];
    //NSLog(@"%@",[num  substringToIndex:3]);
    //NSLog(@"%@",[num substringFromIndex:3]);
    textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@) %@-",[num  substringToIndex:3],[num substringFromIndex:3]];
    if(range.length > 0)
    textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@) %@",[num substringToIndex:3],[num substringFromIndex:3]];
    }
    return YES;

    }else if([textField tag] != 1){

    return NO;

    }

    }

    -(NSString*)formatNumber:(NSString*)mobileNumber
    {

    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@""];

    NSLog(@"%@", mobileNumber);

    int length = [mobileNumber length];
    if(length > 10)
    {
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber substringFromIndex: length-10];
    NSLog(@"%@", mobileNumber);

    }


    return mobileNumber;
    }


    -(int)getLength:(NSString*)mobileNumber
    {

    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@""];

    int length = [mobileNumber length];

    return length;


    }



    Firstcontroller.h

    @interface FirstTVContoller : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate>{
    NSMutableArray *items;
    NSMutableArray *titles;
    NSMutableArray *section2items;
    NSMutableArray *dataArray;
    UITableView *table;
    contactTitle *title;

    //launch title picker
    UIPickerView *titlePicker;
    UILabel *titleLabel;
    UITextField *titleField;
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet;
    UIPickerView *pickerView;
    UITextField *textField;


    UITextField *FirstnameTextfield;
    UITextField *LastnameTextfield;
    UITextField *CompanyTextfield;

    UITextField *phoneTextfield;

    //the scrollview
    UIScrollView *scrollview;

    }
    //attributes for title picker
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray * titlecategories;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray * titleidSlot;


    @end

    FirstTVController.m
    //
    //  FirstTVContoller.m
    //  TwoTableViews



    @implementation FirstTVContoller
    @synthesize titleidSlot;
    @synthesize titlecategories;


    - (BOOL) connectedToNetwork
    {
    // Create zero addy
    struct sockaddr_in zeroAddress;
    bzero(&zeroAddress, sizeof(zeroAddress));
    zeroAddress.sin_len = sizeof(zeroAddress);
    zeroAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;

    // Recover reachability flags
    SCNetworkReachabilityRef defaultRouteReachability = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(NULL, (struct sockaddr *)&zeroAddress);
    SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags;

    BOOL didRetrieveFlags = SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability, &flags);
    CFRelease(defaultRouteReachability);

    if (!didRetrieveFlags)
    {
    //NSLog(@"Error. Could not recover network reachability flags");
    return NO;
    }

    BOOL isReachable = flags & kSCNetworkFlagsReachable;
    BOOL needsConnection = flags & kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired;
    BOOL nonWiFi = flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsTransientConnection;

    NSURL *testURL = [NSURL URLWithString:SERVERNAME];
    NSURLRequest *testRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:testURL  cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:20.0];
    NSURLConnection *testConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:testRequest delegate:self];

    return ((isReachable && !needsConnection) || nonWiFi) ? (testConnection ? YES : NO) : NO;

    }

    -(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];




    //    scrollview = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 500)];
    //    scrollview.pagingEnabled = YES;
    //    
    //    //[scrollview addSubview:self.view];
    //    [self.view addSubview:scrollview];



    table.scrollEnabled = YES;
    dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 290, 30)];

    //dropper
    titleField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 2, 300, 30)];
    titleField.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
    titleField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    NSArray *firstItemsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2", nil];

    NSDictionary *firstItemsArrayDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:firstItemsArray forKey:@"data"];
    [dataArray addObject:firstItemsArrayDict];


    //Second section dat
    NSArray *secondItemsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", nil];
    NSDictionary *secondItemsArrayDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:secondItemsArray forKey:@"data"];
    [dataArray addObject:secondItemsArrayDict];


    NSArray *thirdItemsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3", nil];
    NSDictionary *thirdItemsArrayDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:thirdItemsArray forKey:@"data"];
    [dataArray addObject:thirdItemsArrayDict];

    NSLog(@"the dataArray%@",dataArray);


    if([self connectedToNetwork]){

    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{

    //build the url of strings
    FULLURL = [SERVERNAME stringByAppendingFormat:ushTitleLink];
    //create the url
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:FULLURL];
    //NSLog(@"here title url%@",url);

    //get the data from the url
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: url];
    NSLog(@"here%@",data);

    //get the data from the url
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    NSLog(@"titleid:%@",TITLEID);
    NSLog(@"title categories:%@",titlecategories);

    });

    [table setBounces:NO];


    }else{


    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
    initWithTitle: @"Please Check your internet connection"
    message:@"Enable your internet connection"
    delegate: nil
    cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
    otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    });
    }

    }

    -(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
    return [dataArray count];
    }


    -(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
    //Number of rows it should expect should be based on the section
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [dataArray objectAtIndex:section];
    NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"data"];
    return [array count];

    }

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if(indexPath.section == 1){
    cell.backgroundColor =[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"longdropper300.png"]];

    }
    else{
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
    }


    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 10, 290, 30)];

    static NSString *cellValue = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell =nil;

    if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellValue];
    }
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;

    if ([indexPath section] == 0) {

    //cellValue=[items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    cell.selectionStyle= UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    //textField.tag = 1;
    textField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    textField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    if(indexPath.section == 0){
    //textfield for email
    if ([indexPath row] == 0) {
    textField.tag = 1;
    textField.text = EMAIL;
    textField.textColor= [UIColor blackColor];
    textField.placeholder = @"Email: example@gmail.com";
    textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress;
    textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;

    }
    //textfield for phone number
    else {
    textField.tag = 2;

    if ([PHONENUMBER isEqual: [NSNull null]] && PHONENUMBER == nil && PHONENUMBER == NULL && [PHONENUMBER isEqual: @""]){
    NSLog(@"phone is empty%@",PHONENUMBER);
    //[PHONENUMBER isEqual:@"frank"];

    }else{
    NSLog(@"phone is not empty%@",PHONENUMBER);
    textField.text = PHONENUMBER;

    }

    textField.placeholder = @"Phone: (xxx)xxx-xxxx";
    textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDefault;
    textField.secureTextEntry = NO;
    }
    textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    //textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo; // no auto correction support
    //textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone; // no auto capitalization support
    textField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    //textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever; // no clear 'x' button to the right
    [textField setEnabled: YES];
    textField.delegate = self;
    [cell addSubview:textField];

    }
    }
    if(indexPath.section == 1){

    [titleField setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    titleField.tag = 3;
    titleField.placeholder = @"Select Contact Title";
    titleField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;

    //titleField == textField.tag = 3;
    if ([TITLENAME isEqual: [NSNull null]]){
    NSLog(@"titlename is empty%@",TITLENAME);

    }else{
    NSLog(@"titlename is not empty%@",TITLENAME);
    titleField.text = TITLENAME;
    }


    titleField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    titleField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    titleField.secureTextEntry = NO;
    titleField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo; // no auto correction support
    titleField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone; // no auto capitalization support
    titleField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    titleField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever; // no clear 'x' button to the right
    [titleField setEnabled: NO];
    titleField.delegate = self;

    [cell addSubview:titleField];


    NSLog(@"here is the titlename%@",TITLENAME);

    }

    if(indexPath.section == 2){

    if ([indexPath row] == 0) {

    textField.tag = 4;
    textField.placeholder = @"First Name";
    cell.selectionStyle= UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    if ([FIRSTNAME isEqual: [NSNull null]]){
    NSLog(@"firstname is empty%@",FIRSTNAME);
    textField.text = @"";

    }else{

    textField.text = FIRSTNAME;

    }

    textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress;
    textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
    }

    if([indexPath row] == 1){
    textField.tag = 5;
    textField.placeholder = @"Last Name";


    if ([LASTNAME isEqual: [NSNull null]]){
    NSLog(@"lastname is empty%@",LASTNAME);
    textField.text = @"";

    }else{
    textField.text = LASTNAME;


    }
    textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
    //textField.secureTextEntry = NO;

    }

    if([indexPath row] == 2){

    textField.tag = 6;
    textField.placeholder = @"Company";

    if ([COMPANY isEqual: [NSNull null]]){
    NSLog(@"company is empty%@",COMPANY);
    textField.text = @"";
    }
    else{
    textField.text = COMPANY;
    }

    textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    textField.secureTextEntry = NO;


    }

    //]textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo; // no auto correction support
    textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone; // no auto capitalization support
    textField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever; // no clear 'x' button to the right
    [textField setEnabled: YES];
    textField.delegate = self;
    [cell addSubview:textField];

    }

    return cell;
    }

    //Change the Height of title cell drop down
    -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
    {
    if (indexPath.section == 1) {
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    return 30;
    }
    }
    return 45;
    }



    - (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

    if(([textField tag] == 1)){

    NSString *emailRegEx = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx];
    //Valid email address

    if ([emailTest evaluateWithObject:textField.text] == YES)
    {

    EMAIL = [textField.text copy];
    NSLog(@"here is the email%@",EMAIL);
    }
    else
    {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]

          initWithTitle: @"Bad Email"
          message: @"Please Re-enter the email address with a valid email"
          delegate: nil
          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    textField.text =  nil;
    NSLog(@"email not in proper format");
    }

    }

    if(([textField tag] == 2)){

    //NSString *phoneRegex = @"[235689][0-9]{6}([0-9]{3})?";
    //NSPredicate *phoneTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", phoneRegex];
    //valid email address


    //if ([phoneTest evaluateWithObject:textField.text] == YES)
    // {
    //if(PHONENUMBER != nil){


    NSString *tempString = [textField.text copy];

    NSString *unformatted = tempString;
    NSLog(@"unformatted phonenumber%@",unformatted);

    NSArray *stringComponents = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[unformatted substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 3)],
                 [unformatted substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(3, 3)],
                 [unformatted substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(6, [unformatted length]-6)], nil];

    NSString *formattedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@)%@-%@", [stringComponents objectAtIndex:0], [stringComponents objectAtIndex:1], [stringComponents objectAtIndex:2]];
    NSLog(@"Formatted Phone Number: %@", formattedString);

    PHONENUMBER = formattedString;



    NSLog(@"here is the phone number %@",PHONENUMBER);
    // }
    //        else
    //        {
    //            NSLog(@"Phone Number Invalid");
    //            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
    //                                  initWithTitle: @"xxx-xxx-xxxx"
    //                                  message: @"Please enter a valid phone number"
    //                                  delegate: nil
    //                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
    //                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
    //            [alert show];
    //            textField.text =  nil;
    //        }
    }

    if(([textField tag] == 4)){


    FIRSTNAME = [textField.text copy];
    NSLog(@"here is the firstName%@",FIRSTNAME);
    }
    if(([textField tag] == 5)){


    LASTNAME = [textField.text copy];
    NSLog(@"here is the Last Name%@",LASTNAME);
    }

    if(([textField tag] == 6)){

    COMPANY = [textField.text copy];
    NSLog(@"here is the Company%@",COMPANY);
    }




    return YES;

    }

    -(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textField;
    {
    NSInteger nextTag = textField.tag + 1;
    // Try to find next responder
    UIResponder* nextResponder = [textField.superview viewWithTag:nextTag];
    if (nextResponder) {

    // Found next responder, so set it.
    [nextResponder becomeFirstResponder];
    } else {
    // Not found, so remove keyboard.
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }
    return NO; // We do not want UITextField to insert line-breaks.
    }


    - (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
    //parse out the json data
    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData //1
                                 options:kNilOptions
                                   error:&error];

    title = [[contactTitle alloc] initWithDictionary:json];

    //NSLog(@"here is the dictionary from json: %@", json);
    NSLog(@"here is title that was the json %@", title);
    NSLog(@"here is the title from json: %@", title.cTitle);
    NSLog(@"here is the title id from json %@", title.cTitleID);
    }

    //PickerViewController.m
    - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("data loader", NULL);

    dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{

    TITLENAME =  [title.cTitle objectAtIndex:row], row;
    //NSLog(@"here is the selected title%@", TITLENAME);

    TITLEID =  [title.cTitleID objectAtIndex:row], row;
    //NSLog(@"here is the selected title%@", TITLEID);

    });

    //thePickerView.hidden = YES;

    }

    //PickerView
    - (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView {

    return 1;
    }

    - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    return [title.cTitle count];
    }

    - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [title.cTitle
    objectAtIndex:row];
    }

    - (void)fetchedContactIDData:(NSData *)responseData {
    //parse out the json data

    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData //1
                                 options:kNilOptions
                                   error:&error];

    NSLog(@"here is the login info from json: %@", json);
    // NSString *FALSELOGIN;


    CONTACTID = [json valueForKey:@"contactid"];
    NSLog(@"CONTACT ID: %@", CONTACTID);

    // LOGINID = [json valueForKey:@"login"];
    // NSLog(@"LOGIN ID: %@", LOGINID);

    }


    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //get the country selected
    //NSString *selectedCell = nil;

    if(indexPath.section == 1){

    titleField.text = @"Select Contact Title";
    NSLog(@"you selected:%@",TITLENAME);



    actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                          delegate:nil
                 cancelButtonTitle:nil
            destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                 otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [actionSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];

    CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 40, 0, 0);

    pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];

    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    pickerView.dataSource = self;
    pickerView.delegate = self;

    [actionSheet addSubview:pickerView];

    UISegmentedControl *closeButton = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Cancel"]];
    closeButton.momentary = YES;
    closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(260, 7.0f, 50.0f, 30.0f);
    closeButton.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    closeButton.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [closeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissActionSheet:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [actionSheet addSubview:closeButton];

    //[actionSheet showInView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]];
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
    [actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 485)];

    }else{

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    }


    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];


    }

    - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
    if(([textField tag] == 2)){
    int length = [self getLength:textField.text];
    //NSLog(@"Length  =  %d ",length);

    if(length == 10)
    {
    if(range.length == 0)
    return NO;
    }

    if(length == 3)
    {
    NSString *num = [self formatNumber:textField.text];
    textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@) ",num];
    if(range.length > 0)
    textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[num substringToIndex:3]];
    }
    else if(length == 6)
    {
    NSString *num = [self formatNumber:textField.text];
    //NSLog(@"%@",[num  substringToIndex:3]);
    //NSLog(@"%@",[num substringFromIndex:3]);
    textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@) %@-",[num  substringToIndex:3],[num substringFromIndex:3]];
    if(range.length > 0)
    textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@) %@",[num substringToIndex:3],[num substringFromIndex:3]];
    }
    return YES;

    }else if([textField tag] != 1){

    return NO;

    }

    }

    -(NSString*)formatNumber:(NSString*)mobileNumber
    {

    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@""];

    NSLog(@"%@", mobileNumber);

    int length = [mobileNumber length];
    if(length > 10)
    {
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber substringFromIndex: length-10];
    NSLog(@"%@", mobileNumber);

    }


    return mobileNumber;
    }


    -(int)getLength:(NSString*)mobileNumber
    {

    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@""];

    int length = [mobileNumber length];

    return length;


    }



    - (void)dismissActionSheet:(id)sender{
    [actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    //pickerButton.titleLabel.text = TITLENAME;
    //titleLabel.text= TITLENAME;
    titleField.text = TITLENAME;
    [titleLabel reloadInputViews];
    }

    - (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
    [titlePicker removeConstraints:titlePicker];
    [titlePicker removeFromSuperview];

    }

    @end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after reviewing your code i found one thing see below here is the problem

```
 if(([textField tag] == 2)){

    //something
    return YES;
    }
    else if([textField tag] != 1){

    return NO;

    }
```

in else if block you keep return NO it means it doesn't take any input text , change that one to return YES it'l work.